# NSZombieEnabled isn't helping my obj_msgSend

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with my iPhone app on `0x01ad809b  <+0015>  mov    0x8(%edx),%edi`

I have `NSZombieEnabled` set to `YES` but I'm not seeing any class printed out in the debugger like I normally do.

Is there another way to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a crash caused, most likely, by corruption of memory, using a variable that isn't initialized, and/or casting a non-object type to an object.

First, post the backtrace of the crash.  That will provide more context.

Second, try Build and Analyze.  Fix any of the problems that it identifies.

Finally, if this is a new crash, go back to a revision right before the crash and then roll forward until you hit the crash.  What are the changes made over that span of time?

With more context -- the crash log, in particular (or backtrace, at the least) -- more specific debugging techniques can be offered.

Comment: 0 objc_msgSend_fpret

4 [NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:]

Comment: That doesn't help;  edit your question and show the backtrace of the crash.  And did you build&analyze?

Comment: There wasn't any backtrace beyond this. Stepping through code though I was able to find that I was retaining an object without checking if it was nil first.

Comment: `[nil retain]` is a no-op;  should have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I guess this is one of those problems that fixed itself through the course of fixing other problems. I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score -1):

You can select Breakpoint navigator and add breakpoint on all exceptions. Maybe it will help.

Try with malloc info as well.

Comment: This isn't an exception.   It is a crash.  EXC_BAD_ACCESS cannot be caught.

Answer (score -1):

Use Instruments to Profile and detect zombies instead.

1. Change the build target to the Simulator
2. In the `Build` menu, select `Profile`
3. Instruments will open, then select the `Zombies` instrument

This automatically sets up the `NSZombieEnabled` flag and will popup a message whenever a dealloced object is messaged. Clicking the disclosure will show the memory management events of the object.

Comment: Well it's still obviously a corrupted memory issue and zombies are the best way to debug. I gave an easier method to ensure it's turned on correctly

Comment: You can't debug corrupted memory issues with zombies.   You can only detect over-released objects with zombies.  The corruption that results from that is a side effect of the over-release.  The OP stated he has already tried zombie detection and it doesn't work, indicating that the problem is not an over-release issue.

Comment: Fair point, just an EXC_BAD_ACCESS from a obj_msgSend is almost always a memory management bug in which zombies would help. Based on the OP's wording it sounded like NSZombieEnabled wasn't actually turned on correctly.